# Computing a Sequence of People Entering and Leaving a Room

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, permutations, towers-of-hanoi

I've been working on a problem for my Algorithms class, but I've found myself stuck. The prompt is as follows.

> You start with an empty room and a group of n people waiting outside. At each step, you may either admit one person into the room, or let one out. Please design an algorithm which generates a sequence of $2^n − 1$ steps, so that every possible combination of people is achieved exactly once. For example, for $n = 3$, one possible sequence would be
>
> $\qquad\displaystyle e_1, e_2, x_1, e_3, e_1, x_2, x_1$.
>
> where $e_i$ means person $i$ enters the room and $x_j$ means person $j$ exits
>   the room
>
> Hint: study the Hanoi Tower algorithm.

In my research on the prompt, I've found many people referencing [Gray Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), but I don't understand how to implement it in an algorithm to compute this combination. I also found a very similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562989/using-2n-steps-to-get-every-possible-combination-of-people-in-a-room), but there wasn't an actual implementation of it.

It would be greatly appreciated if you could point me in the right direction on where to go with this algorithm.

Comment: Assume you have a sequence that does what you want for $n$ people. Can you use it to get one for $n+1$ people? Or, going the route of Gray code: do you understand you Gray codes are an answer? The Wikipedia article contains code examples.

Comment: I understand your hint fully, I've done recursion problems before, but I'm struggling with the implementation. For example, what would be the best way to store whether or not a user is in the room? I'm looking for a bit more of an actual example of how to do it, not just theoretical hints.

Comment: In that case, I recommend you outline your algorithmic idea in the question. (If actual programming is your issue, [SO] is the place to go.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Base case** It's easy to generate the combinations when $n=1$: just use the operation $e_1$.

**Recursion** Now assume that you have a sequence $ops_n$ that will generate all the combinations of $n$ people. Define $rops_n$ to be the sequence of operations that "undoes" $ops_n$, namely first form the reverse of $ops_n$ and then replace all "enter" operations with "leave" operations and *vice versa*. For example, if $ops_2 = \langle\, e_1, e_2, x_1\,\rangle$, then $rops_n =\langle\, e_1, x_2, x_1\,\rangle$. It's not difficult to see that $ops_n, rops_n$ will generate all the combinations of $n$ people and then produce the same combinations in reverse order.

Finally, show that if $ops_n$ generates all the $n$-combinations, then the sequence $ops_n, e_{n+1}, rops_n$ will generate all the $(n+1)$-combinations: first all the ones without person $n+1$ and then all the ones with person $n+1$. From this construction it's clear inductively that you can generate all $n$ combinations with $2^n-1$ operations.

---

As per the hint you were given, this is very similar in spirit to the Towers of Hanoi problem: To move $n+1$ disks from peg 1 to peg 2, you first move $n$ disks from peg 1 to peg 3, then move the largest disk to peg 2, and finally move the $n$ disks on peg 3 to peg 2.